# Unable to dismiss notification from notification bar in react native push notification (Android)

Tags: android, push-notification, react-native, react-native-push-notification

I'm creating a remainder application in which I couldn't able to dismiss the notification from the notification area, I've tried many methods to resolve this but still, nothing helps, 
`PushNotification.clearLocalNotification(parseInt(notification.id, 10));` tried this to dismiss notification (not removing/cancelling). also tried similar solution like `` PushNotification.cancelLocalNotifications({ id: `${parseInt(notification.id, 10)}` }); ``.  but still, nothing helps. I tried logging the node package, I could see the logging inside the clear notification java function/cancel function, still not dismissing from the notification area

Edit: I want to dismiss the notification on the action (button) press.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `autoCancel: true` to dismiss notification on notification tap

```
export const LocalNotification = () => {
  PushNotification.localNotification({
    autoCancel: true,
    bigText:
      'This is local notification demo in React Native app. Only shown, when expanded.',
    subText: 'Local Notification Demo',
    title: 'Local Notification Title',
    message: 'Expand me to see more',
    vibrate: true,
    vibration: 300,
    playSound: true,
    soundName: 'default',
    actions: '["Yes", "No"]'
  })
}
```

Comment: Sorry I didn't mention earlier, I need to dismiss the notification on action button press

Comment: Ive used autoCancel: true still notification is not disappering after clicking.. @HariharanSivakumar